# Screen is getting frozen while installing Ubuntu as dual boot

Tags: grub2, screen, freeze

I tried to install ubuntu with windows 10 as dual boot . but installation is getting frozen (screen freeze)  when it reaches install grub2.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it so happens that grub doesn't install properly with usb 3.0, so try switching ports if you are doing it on usb 3.0. If this is not the case, try changing the bios settings to UEFI mode and try again!

Comment: I am trying to boot from DVD